# Empty image when uploading to presigned AWS S3 url in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload image to AWS S3 in my React Native(expo managed workflow), but in result the file is empty. I don't get any errors through the process. I've also tried to upload it using Uppy AWS plugin, but result is the same. Here is my code:

```
async function getUploadUrl(filename: string, type: string) {
  const response = await fetch(GET_UPLOAD_URL(filename, type), {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  });
  return await response.json();
}


export default async function uploadImage(
  file: Blob,
  filename: string,
  base64: string
) {
  const uploadData = await getUploadUrl(filename, file.type);

  const data = new FormData();
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(uploadData.fields)) {
    data.append(key, value as string);
  }
  data.append('file', Buffer.from(base64, 'base64'));
  let res = await fetch(uploadData.url, {
    method: 'post',
    body: data,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
    },
  });
```

I am using expo image picker to get the file. I've also tried to upload just Blob file insead of Buffer, but it doesn't work either

Here is how the file looks if i open it in browser https://prnt.sc/vOk5CI7lyPhu

Comment: How are you determining that "the file is empty"?

Comment: @jarmod if i open it in browser and check the source tab in dev tools, the file is just empty. I've atached a screenshot

Comment: That's not a good way to test that the object was uploaded correctly. Go to the S3 console or use the awscli to download the file from S3. Is it the same size and content as the originally-uploaded file?

Comment: unfortunately i don't have access to the S3 console

Comment: OK, use curl or wget with a pre-signed URL, fetch the file locally, then compare it.

Comment: I downloaded it using curl, and the size is zero

Comment: And you verified that the length of the data buffer that you originally uploaded was not zero? Also check [this example](https://www.webiny.com/blog/upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-pre-signed-post-data-and-a-lambda-function-7a9fb06d56c1), see the uploadFileToS3 function.

Comment: I've just checked the size of it right before the part where i pass it to FormData and it is defenitely not zero

Comment: Also i've just tried the same aproach from the example you've shared, but same result. The status is 204, but no image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone also faced such problem, i managed to upload the file by uri like this:

```
formData.append('file', {
    uri: uri,
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    name: filename,
  });
```